# How to check the correct Training Class In PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new with Pytorch, I tried to write my training class, but I had this error

```python
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

import tqdm

class MLPNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLPNet, self).__init__()
        self.first_fully_connected = nn.Linear(8*8, 100)
        self.last_fully_connected = nn.Linear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 8*8) # reshape input tensor to the size (batch_size, 8*8)
        x = F.sigmoid(self.first_fully_connected(x))
        x = F.sigmoid(self.last_fully_connected(x))
        return x


def training(mlp, X, y, epochs=1, lr=.2, batch_size=101):               
    # solver
    # loss
    solver = torch.optim.SGD(mlp.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() #  nn.NLLLoss()

    n_batches = (len(X) + batch_size - 1) // batch_size
    for epoch in tqdm.tqdm(range(epochs)):
        for i in range(n_batches):
            slice_ = np.s_[i::n_batches]
            X_batch = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X[slice_])).float()
            y_batch = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y[slice_, np.newaxis])).float()

#             X_batch = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X[slice_])).long()
#             y_batch = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y[slice_, np.newaxis])).long()

            print(type(X_batch.data))
            print(type(y_batch.data))
            ### BEGIN: your optim step here. do not forget to reset gradients

            # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
            solver.zero_grad()

            prediction = mlp(X_batch)
            # Forward pass to get output/logits
            #outputs = mlp(X_batch)

            # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
            #loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
            loss_f = loss(prediction, y_batch)

            # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
            loss_f.backward()

            # Updating parameters
            solver.step()                              
            ### END

    return mlp

mlp = nn.Sequential(
    #### Your net here    
    nn.Linear(2, 64),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64, 2)
)
model_mlp = training(mlp, X_std, y_std)
```

But I got this error, 
I tried the change the type but still faced that error. 
I tried the changed the loss function too but still that error.

**RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)**
 **in ()**
**----> 1 model_mlp = fit(mlp, X_std, y_std)**

**RuntimeError: Expected object of type Variable[torch.FloatTensor] but found** **type Variable[torch.LongTensor] for argument #1 'mat1'**

I really appreciate any help you can provide.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As edited in the question by @Ioannis Nasios, you had

```
X_batch = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X[slice_])).long()
```

Which means that your input tensors to your MLP were `long` integers, but the network requires floats. So you need to have:

```
X_batch = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X[slice_])).float()
```

And this should solve your error.